# <iframe>, how to resize responsive pages

Tags: html, css, iframe, responsive-design

I want to embed multiple remote pages into one using `<iframe>`.

The main problem arises when I resize the browser page horizontally: if the remote pages are responsive, they adapt as much as possible to the available space changing their content.

Alas this is not what I want: I need to keep them as they are full screen scaling their image to the available space.

Is it something that can be done using CSS?

Second minor question due to my very limited of CSS and its headaches: why in my examples the two page-containers are vertically so wide apart?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Title here</title>

        <style>
            body {
                background-color: yellow;
                padding: 10px;
            }

            .content-wrapper {
                width: 80%;
                padding: 10px;
                overflow: hidden;
                float: left;
                border: 5px solid red;
                background-color: pink;
            }

            .page-container {
                width: 1280px;
                height: 768px;
                border: 10px solid green;
                background-color: lightgreen;

                padding: 10px;

                -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
                -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
                -o-transform: scale(0.5);
                -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
                -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
                -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
            }

            iframe {
                width: 80%;
                height: 80%;
                margin: 20px;

                border: 10px solid blue;
                background-color: lightblue;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        yellow: body<br>

        <div class="content-wrapper">
            red: content wrapper

            <div class="page-container">
                green: page-container
                <br>
                <br>
                blue: iframe
                <br>
                <iframe src="http://www.drexel.edu"></iframe>
            </div>

            <div class="page-container">
                green: page-container
                <br>
                <br>
                blue: iframe
                <br>
                <iframe src="http://forefathersgroup.com/"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*Background note: in the real code the pages are provided by a Bokeh/Flask server. They are plots that don't behave too well when scaled down, as legend and texts are kept the original size and hide the glyphs. I don't want them to be responsive!*

Comment: If you cannot control the iFrame's content styling, and it's not responsive, there's nothing you can do that I can think of.

Comment: @KobyDouek, the problem is the opposite: the remote site IS responsive. I want to load it full view, without it to adapt to the reduced size of the local frame.